# How to set image slider on header in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image

I am new in android developing please help me. 
I want to set image slider at the top on page and image are dynamic come through web service. example of image slider like below:-[image]

just like a slider show in this image (Back Story shop fro Backpacks) same i also want and remember image are dynamic.

My activity.main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_outer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_outer">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            custom:pager_animation="Accordion"
            custom:auto_cycle="true"
            custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
            custom:pager_animation_span="1100" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_product_horizontal_scroll_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_produce_image01"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/shop240x320"
                            android:paddingRight="65dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/special_producr"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_produce_image02"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/shop240x320"
                            android:paddingRight="65dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/special_producr"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_produce_image03"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/shop240x320"
                            android:paddingRight="65dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/special_producr"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_produce_image04"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/shop240x320"
                            android:paddingRight="65dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/special_producr"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_special_produce_image05"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/shop240x320"
                            android:paddingRight="65dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/special_producr"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>  
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView></RelativeLayout>
```

currently it showing like this:-

[image]

and this give also a error Failed to find style 'SliderStyle' in current theme what is the meaning

Comment: use `ViewPager` with layout beneath...

Comment: I try but i can't set image dynamic in view pager

Comment: ViewPager with PagerAdapter or FragmentPagerAdapter is something that you should look into.

Comment: This can be achieve by viewpager with page indicator(for the dots below). You need to post your code for better explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to make it yourself, use nice and simple libraries. [Here](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of ways to achieve what you want like :
1. Via Using View Pager.
2. Using Recycler View (and set Layout Manager Orientation HORIZONTAL).

These Above two are the simplest and basic widgets use to render Image view(or other views) in above mentioned design format.

Now there is one more thing what you need is : to render Your Actual image in these Image Views.
I assume you are getting a list of Url's from some web service. Now you need to render those url's into your ImageView. For this you can use 3rd party library like picaso or Aquery.

the key part is In your adapter which you are attaching to these widgets, first pass the list of Urls to that Adapter and then set Image View Source with the help of one of these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library
https://github.com/MoeidHeidari/banner

implementation 'com.github.MoeidHeidari:banner:1.04'

In your activity

BannerLayout banner=(BannerLayout) findViewById(R.id.Banner);

```
    List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
    urls.add("http://szzljy.com/images/mountain/mountain4.jpg");
    urls.add("http://szzljy.com/images/mountain/mountain4.jpg");
    urls.add("http://www.visitgreece.gr/deployedFiles/StaticFiles/Photos/Generic%20Contents/Forests/mountains_2_560.jpg");
    urls.add("http://szzljy.com/images/mountain/mountain4.jpg");
    urls.add("http://www.visitgreece.gr/deployedFiles/StaticFiles/Photos/Generic%20Contents/Forests/mountains_2_560.jpg");
    urls.add("http://szzljy.com/images/mountain/mountain4.jpg");


    BaseBannerAdapter webBannerAdapter=new BaseBannerAdapter(this,urls);
    webBannerAdapter.setOnBannerItemClickListener(new BannerLayout.OnBannerItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position)
        {


        }
    });
    banner.setAdapter(webBannerAdapter);
```